# Value of dfs.blocksize and BlockCapacity is different

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh, hdp

BlockCapacity given in the REST response of NameNode is different than what we have set in the Ambari under HDFS `dfs.blocksize`.

Fetching the block capacity using following REST request

`https://<namenode-ip>:50470/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=FSNamesystem`

I am getting the value for BlockCapacity is 2097152 which is equivalent to 2MB.

[image: REST Response of Namenode]

The value of `dfs.blocksize` in Ambari is 128MB by default.

[image: Configured Value on Ambari]

Is BlockCapacity from NameNode REST API response and `dfs.blocksize` from Ambari are the same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BlockCapacity** refers to the total number of blocks HDFS can hold. The value is computed based on the allocated Namenode's heapsize. The requires heapsize can be derived based on the values configured for `dfs.replication`, `dfs.blocksize` and the total DFS capacity.

Examples found [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/admin_nn_memory_config.html) describe how these configurations help in deciding the namenode's heapsize thereby determining the block capacity.

In this case, the filesystem can hold a total of **2097152** blocks (excluding replication) each with the configured `dfs.blocksize` as the maximum size per block.

Comment: How can we sure about this? Is there any documentation about this which i should refer?

Comment: Yes. You can refer to the examples in namenode's memory configuration [here](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-12-x/topics/admin_nn_memory_config.html) or the metrics explained [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Metrics.html#FSNamesystem)

Comment: But its not correct i think, I have one test machine which has the Single node hadoop cluster installed on it and it has total 100GB of space, if we say BlockCapacity is number of blocks then according to your explanation it will be like 2097152 x 128mb = 268,435,456‬ / 1024 = 262144gb it will leads to miscalculation. let me know if i'm calculating it on wrong way.

Comment: If all the blocks are going to be 128MB in size, with your current cluster storage capacity of 100GB, you can store a maximum of 800 blocks (`100*1024/128`). You would have exhausted the storage capacity by then, whereas your namenode's heapsize dictates that it can hold upto 2MM blocks. I assume that the Namenode's  Heapsize is configured to be atleast  2GB.

Comment: I din't get you, Is it possible that i have wrong configuration?
Actually i haven't set any value manually on Ambari, the configuration is default config provided by the Ambari except SSL configuration.

Comment: The configuration has no issues, the stated block capacity is more than the actual available storage, which is usually common in clusters of low storage capacity. Block Capacity is determined by the capacity of the metadata objects that the namenode can hold in its memory. This should be always greater than or equal to the Storage Capacity of the cluster to be able to fully utilize the Storage Volumes.

Comment: while calculating the block capacity value the machine disk space considered or not?

Where should we found the block size value in rest response?

Comment: No, The User must take the disk space into account while deciding the namenode's heapsize.